# How to accept SSH Host keys programmatically if fingerprint is known?

Tags: ssh

I don't want to use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option, but I want to save the public key of the server in a file and use this public key on every connection, even IP address or port is changed.

When `-o UserKnownHostsFile=myfile` option is used, ssh still asks for verification if we connect the same machine over a different IP.

How to tell `ssh` to save a public key in a different location and use this public key in current connection? Example usage:

```
# there is no 'foo-public.key' file at this moment
ssh -o TheMagicalOption=foo-public.key user@example.com -p 1234

The authenticity of host 'xxxxxxxx' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:LR5wDKrEmHD0QhRcAmxTxBnzWIRmNUfJyeawhKw+W38.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? [YES]

# 'foo-public.key' is created at this point 
on-target $ exit 

# another port forward is made, so the same server is on port 5678
ssh -o TheMagicalOption=foo-public.key user@example.com -p 5678
# not asking the same verification question
on-target $
```

Comment: That sounds like you might be interested in _signed host keys_? These replace the whole fingerprint thing with a trusted party (can be yourself) signing the host key and the client being configured to trust the trusted party. I don't know if you sign the hostname, though, you might want to consult the ssh manpage for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=ask \
    -o HashKnownHosts=no \
    -o CheckHostIP=no \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=example_fp \
    -p 1234 user@example.com
```

to obtain the key.

- `HashKnownHosts=no` ensures, that the host name will be saved in clear text
- `CheckHostIP=no` is used to identify the host by name only

the result in `example_fp` will be a line starting like

```
[example.com]:1234 ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAA...
```

When using standard port 22 on the first connection you'll see

```
example.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAA...
```

So either use port 22 on the first connection or edit the file afterwards to remove the port number. When connecting next time, this line will match on any port number.

Comment: [Changing `example.com` with `*`](https://github.com/aktos-io/dcs-tools/blob/89510be162b8c293b24b011757d8f50aec87ec19/common.sh#L28) matches with any host name also. Thank you.

Comment: Another way to override the host key used for checking is with `-o HostKeyAlias=<name>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such magic option that would do that. You can either store the public key manually in advance (if it is known), or use some expect script, that will write "yes" for you in case the fingerprint is "correct".

Answer (score 2):

One workaround could be to use `ssh-keyscan`, as an additional step, to obtain the ssh fingerprint(s), and then replace the host field with a wildcard `*` before saving it to a file. E.g:

```
$ ssh-keyscan -p 1234 example.com | perl -pe 's/.*? /* /' > example_fp
```

You then reference `example_fp` whenever you need to connect to this server (regardless of port/dns/ip):

```
$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=example_fp -p 4321 user@example.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ssh-keyscan` is a little bit problematic and does not return any output in many cases. Try to `ssh myhost -R 1234:localhost:22 -L 4567:localhost:1234` and `ssh-keyscan -p 4567 localhost` to see if you could obtain any outputs. (You will still be able to `ssh localhost -p 4567` though)

Answer (score 1):

If you have (a copy of) the server's pubkey file as your name suggests, you can use it to create a temporary known_hosts file like:

```
sshfoo() {
  # assumes first arg is always user@host, otherwise adjust
  echo ${1#*@} $(cat foo-pubkey) >temp_myhosts
  ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=temp_myhosts "$@"
  # or if you don't have anything you need in .ssh/known_hosts,
  # just overwrite that and omit the -o 
  rm temp_myhosts # or just leave it and replace it next time
}
# can use ssh for the function name if you always want this change,
# or if in the cases you don't want it you remember to override 
# with command ssh or $(which ssh) or /bin/ssh or whatever
```

If you actually have an existing known_hosts line (which is a host field followed by the contents of the pubkey file) you can similarly modify that:

```
awk -vh="${1#*@}" "{$1=h;print}" <hosts_line >temp_myhosts
```

or if you have a file with that line among others, perhaps the usual known_hosts:

```
awk -vh="${1#*@}" "$1~/oldname/{$1=h} 1" <.ssh/known_hosts >temp_myhosts
```

et cetera et cetera ad Yul Brynner.